# Rank in a Convex Combination

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, data-structures, probability-theory

Given vectors $A, B \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, $w \in [0,1]$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$, let

$$
Rank(A,B,w,x)=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \boldsymbol 1 \{w A_{i} +(1-w) B_{i} < x\}
$$

denote the number of elements in the $w$-weighted convex combination of $A$ and $B$ that are smaller than $x$. I would like to compute $Rank(A,B,w,x)$ for different values of $w$ and $x$ while $A$ and $B$ remain fixed.

Is there a data structure $S(A,B)$ that helps compute $Rank(A,B,w,x)$ in less than $O(n)$ time?

Answer (score 2):

By [duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duality_(projective_geometry)), this problem is equivalent to the halfplane range query problem.

For the worst-case complexity, there is a known space-time tradeoff of [1]:

- $O(n^2/\log^2 n)$ data structure size and $O(\log n)$ query time.
- $O(n)$ data structure size and $O(\sqrt n)$ query time.

[1] Agarwal, P. K. (2017). Range searching. In *Handbook of discrete and computational geometry* (pp. 1057-1092). Chapman and Hall/CRC. [https://www.csun.edu/~ctoth/Handbook/HDCG3.html](https://www.csun.edu/%7Ectoth/Handbook/HDCG3.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can answer each query in $O(\log n)$ time, using a [sweepline algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_line_algorithm) combined with a [persistent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure) [self-balancing binary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree).

Since $wA_i+(1-w)B_i$ is a linear function of $w$, each $i$ corresponds to a line in the 2D $wx$ plane.  In this way we obtain $n$ lines in the plane.  During preprocessing, use the [Bentley-Ottmann algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bentley%E2%80%93Ottmann_algorithm) on these $n$ lines and save the persistent self-balancing binary tree it constructs.  Augment each node in each binary tree with a count of the number of leaves below it (this can be made to work with a persistent data structure too).

Now, given $w,x$, in $O(\log n)$ time we can find the appropriate instance of the persistent tree that corresponds to $w$; then look up $x$ in this tree (which can be done in $O(\log n)$ time), and find the number of leaves that fall before $x$ in the ordering (which can also be done in $O(\log n)$ time, thanks to the augmentation).

The running time for the precomputation is $O((n+k)\log n)$, where $k$ counts the number of intersections between these lines.  In practice, I would expect that typically $k=O(n)$ (e.g., for random problem instances), so typically precomputation can be done in $O(n\log n)$ time.